Calculate distance and time travelled by a truck
I am currently working on a model which is similar to the Airport Delivery model in Anylogic. There are multiple Houses a Truck is delivering from a Hub. The model works so far so good.
Now I would like to calculate prices for each package that is delivered. For that I need distance the truck travelled and time the truck has travelled. But my functions don't work.
My process flow
My Agents
I tried the getDistanceTravelled(Agent agent) function in movedTo. But I don't understand what to insert in the brackets.

btw, looks like your Database is broken, but that is a different issue. Also, do not simply write "my functions don't work". You need to help us help you. What did you want? What did you try? What did you see? What is the setup. All as concise as possible :) Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow


I tried the getDistanceTravelled(Agent agent) function in movedTo. But I don't understand what to insert in the brackets.

You need to specify the agent you want to get the distance travelled for. AnyLogic internally logs the distance for each agent, but it cannot know which agent you want to query.
If you "ask" from within a Truck, you can simply use getDistanceTravelled(this)
Study this help page in detail, this is a core skill to understand for any model.

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. The moveTo is in the Hub agent. I created a pool of Trucks there. Do you know, what I need to type to specify that I mean those trucks?

pls always open new (specific) questions in new issues, SOF is not a forum, see these tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
